# How to append new url hash parameters on search button click?

Tags: sxa, content-search

We are extending the Location Filter rendering with distance and services dropdowns. On the search button click we need to append the distance and services filtering values to url as hash parameters. What's the best approach to perform this change Or are there any other options that we can consider achieve this ?

Comment: Try this.There should be searchbox js where your search query url is getting created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the existing function of `XA.component.search.query` (defined in `component-search-query.js`). For example:

```
var hash = {};
hash["key"] = "value";
XA.component.search.query.updateHash(hash);
```

Keep in mind that each of the search components supports search results signatures (you can assign some of the filters to one Search Results rendering and others to second Search Results on the same page). If you want to support this you need to include the signature in hash parameters. This is done in all of the scripts so you have plenty of examples how to do it.

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you Dawid

Comment: @dawid: hash["key"] = "value"; In this code from where it will read the data, is it from the search index?